# Automatic lock GPS location in QField app

Tags: qgis, qfield, qfieldsync, qfield-cloud

Is it possible to automatically lock GPS location in QField project file and cannot be deactivated, so that the users cannot manually move the point location when collecting the point data (the point data will be automatically placed according to their current location to make sure the point is truly created on their current location, similar to Garmin GPS handheld) ?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Dziyad

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Comment: yes..what I want is, when someone open the QField project and he/she starts the editing mode to create a point data, the lock positioning is always active (cannot be deactivated) to make sure he/she is truly on that point when creating a point data

Answer (score 0):

So far, what I can do is to set Positioning Information Variables so that it will come out with the information of whether the crosshair is snapped to the sensor or not when creating a point.  It is actually good enough